# Extracting data for _sent Data View via FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views, ftp, data-extract

I have multiple journey builder emails using transactional API and I want to extract daily data for sends and clicks. Using sends as an example, I have created an Automation with these steps:

1. `Schedule`
2. `SQL QUERY` - query the `_sent` data view to extract daily journey builder email sends - and I can find the data is available in the `sent_data_extension` once I run this step.
3. `Data Extract` - extracting the data from the `sent_data_extension` (here when I run the automation at this point, is it possible to see this data extract, if so where? Either way this is also is successful.)
4. `File Transfer` - pulling the data into the SF marketing cloud ftp - **this is breaking** and I receive this error:  `File not found matching the pattern EnhancedSFTP://Import/xxxxxxxx.csv`

Are the steps above correct and in the right order? Should  first use data extract to create the .csv for the data found in the `sent_data_extension` and then only can I transfer file to ftp. OR SHOULD I be querying the data view and then immediately transferring the data to ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you outlined are correct and in the right order.

- The Data Extract activity extracts the data from the Data Extension to a .csv file.
- The File Transfer activity transfers the .csv file from the Safehouse
  to the Marketing Cloud FTP.

You can troubleshoot using:

1. Confirm that the Data Extract activity is correctly configured and completed successfully.
2. Verify the File Transfer activity is looking in the correct location
   (Safehouse) and for the correct file name. **The Source Directory should be set to Safehouse and the File Naming Pattern should match the name of the .csv file exactly as it's created by the Data Extract activity**
3. Ensure the File Transfer activity does not run before the Data Extract activity has finished.